# How to make this in Java (MenuBar with drop down)?

Tags: java, user-interface

In MSN Messenger they use this type of control everywhere.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uatm3.png

In the GUI of an application I am making I really want to use something of this nature. Any ideas on how to make something like this?

Answer (score 2):

I think these are often called **SplitButtons**.

- There is a JavaLobby [article about creating something oneself](http://java.dzone.com/news/drop-down-buttons-swing-new-al).
- The [JIDE](http://www.jidesoft.com/) library has a widget called [JideSplitButton](http://www.jdocs.com/jide/2.0/com/jidesoft/swing/JideSplitButton.html).
- The [Japura](http://www.japura.org/) project has a [split button widget](http://www.japura.org/splitbutton.html).
- ... and of course ask Google for more ...